# Invalid JSON is being generated in Postman

Tags: postman

I’m trying to compose a request based on a response. I have the following pre-request script:

```
// Get the response.
var stageResponse = pm.variables.get("getResponse");
// Update some data.
entity = stageResponse.user.entities[0];
entity.value = "married";
// Setup the request.
var requestString = JSON.stringify(stageResponse);
// !!!console.log(requestString) logs the object in the correct json syntax.
pm.environment.set('requestBody', requestString);
```

And in the body, I have: {{requestBody}}

The problem is that the response has the following element:

```
{
"id": "123",
"description": "Why won't your spouse be a co-signer?",
}
But looking at the code after making the call, I see:

{
"id":"123",
"description":"Why won'\''t your spouse be a co-signer?"
}
```

which is not valid JSON. I cannot do any string manipulation since the pre-request value looks OK.

I’m running version 8.0.7

You can try a simple test using the following:

[image]

Comment: Try saving the variable like this `pm.environment.set('requestString', JSON.stringify(requestString))`

Comment: I tried that. Same error. But this time, I noticed an extra quote on the outside. So I removed JSON function calls, but the output was an [object, object] which was predictable...